# Focusing Element Prevents role="alert" Content From Being Announced

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accessibility, nvda

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitButton').click(function (){
    $('#password').focus();
    loadSRValidationMessages('#alertContainer', '.adhocError');
  });
});


function loadSRValidationMessages(n, t) {
    $(n).empty();
    var content = "";
    $(t).each(function() {
        var t = $(this).text();
        if (t.length > 0) {
          content += "<p>" + t + "<\/p>";
        }
    })
    $(n).append('<div id="alerts" role="alert" aria-atomic="true">' + content + '</div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alertContainer">

</div>

<form id="loginForm">
  <input type="password" id="password" required><br/>
  <label class="adhocError">An example error.</label>
  <button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I would like to present is an issue in which it seems as though focusing on an element interrupts, or perhaps prevents, the screen reader (NVDA) from announcing new role="alert" content. I have performed some research and looked at some existing Similar questions, though have yet to find a solution (ideally, having the screen reader announce new alert content as well as focusing on an element).

I have a simple scenario using jQuery. The code is abbreviated. Please let me know if you find any other information necessary.

Comment: Swap the order of events, when you manage focus you will interrupt the `alert`. So if you focus the invalid fields and then set the alert it should work. However, if you are managing focus a much better way would be to just use `aria-labelledby` on the element you are focusing, pointing at the relevant error for the field in question. This is assuming all other WAI-ARIA is present on the input such as `aria-invalid` etc.

Comment: *"if valid then submit"* - why do you have this conditional?  You know this logic is already built into the Validate plugin... it automatically blocks the submit, checks for validity, and then submits if valid.   There are also a bunch of options you could configure for custom handling of things such as focus invalid.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - I verified that what you said is true in the code snippet editor, though when I attempted to switch the order of events in the full code, the behavior did not change. I'm afraid I did not give enough code. I'm working on reproducing the behavior in a code snippet.

Comment: Super, drop an @mention when you have a snippet that replicates behaviour and I will look at it, normally it is something super easy to fix once we spot the problem (is that not just development? )

Comment: @Sparky - I changed the default behavior when I was attempting to avoid Validate focusing on an invalid element, which seemed to interrupt NVDA reading the alert. It was changed during troubleshooting, perhaps unnecessarily and will most likely be reverted once resolved.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - I added a snippet where the alert is only partially read by NVDA when focus is given to a field. If the focus statement is commented out, it will read all of the alert content.

Comment: @Sparky - I removed jQuery Validation from consideration for simplicity and added a snippet. If you have some time, I was wondering if you could perhaps have a look, give me any other feedback you may have.

Comment: No problem, I have a full-on day today but I will try and have a look tomorrow morning for you, I can't see anything obvious but `role="alert"` is not normally updated in this way so it could be that, have you tried changing it to `aria-live="assertive"` as the result is essentially the same but implemented differently. I will check out the compatibility tables etc. & see if there is a known problem with having an existing `role="alert"` element & then adding content to it as I wouldn't use it that way (I would create the whole alert in code & then insert the whole element). Leave it with me.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I updated the snippet with your suggestion to create and insert the whole alert and it seems to be working. I also tested this with the original code. I think the question is resolved. Thank you. Would you like to submit an answer?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! 

I have added some general advice for handling `aria-live` regions (which includes `role="alert"`) in an application that will hopefully make sense and make managing stuff like this easier. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way the `role="alert"` element works in some browser / screen reader combinations a more robust way is to add the full alert message **and it's container** to the page, rather than updating the text within the container.

If you need to issue multiple alerts you should just add multiple alert containers to the page (and ultimately remove the old alert containers, either via a close / dismiss button or when the alert is no longer relevant).

If you want to add multiple updates to a page, a better tactic is to place an `aria-live="assertive"` region onto the page and add / update content within that.

I find that the best way to handle updates for screen readers in a web application is to have a single `aria-live="assertive"` region on the page and have a central message queue in JavaScript (JS), with a delay between each message.

If you have something like a chat application or something that is not "urgent" that you don't want to interrupt a screen reader user with a second `aria-live="polite"` region can be added (using a second messages queue handled by JS).

That way you end up with two simple queues to add messages to `messages.assertive` and `messages.polite` and you will eliminate a load of problems associated with lots of `aria-live` regions (which include `role="alert"` regions).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Graham's view of the issue that if the focus event happens after the `role="alert"` is set, then the alert will be interrupted. Swap the order - first place focus on the invalid field, then set the `role="alert"`.

Use both `aria-invalid="true"` on the invalid field, as well as link the specific error message to the field using `aria-describedby`, which will announce the error after the field label and value. (I wouldn't recommend `aria-labelledby` for linking the error message to the field as that attribute is used to program the field label, not the description, and you may end up confusing the user if you use `aria-labelledby` for the error message).

```
<div class="sr-only" id="errorList" role="alert" aria-atomic="true"></div>

<form id="frmlogin">
// Add aria-invalid, aria-labelledby, aria-describedby attributes to the field
<input type="text" id="name" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="somelabel" aria-describedby="errorList"/>
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    if ($('#frmlogin').valid()) {
        $('#frmlogin').submit();
    }
    else {
        // Swap order of focus event and validation message so focus happens first
        var validator = $("#frmlogin").validate();
        validator.focusInvalid();
        // Set the aria-invalid attribute to the field that has the error
        $("#frmlogin").setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
        // Load the validation messages
        loadSRValidationMessages('#errorList', '.field-validation-error');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I've attempted to use existing elements for announcements (and their associations, like label or description), for some reason, the elements are announced out of order. One of the current requirements is that the elements are announced in order. I also tried reordering the events, without luck. I've created a snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean when you say the elements are announced out of order - could you give us a bit more info? When I run your code snippet, the screen reader doesn't announce the edit field label (because the `<label>` doesn't use the `for` attribute), and the error message isn't linked to the edit field using `aria-describedby`. The error message is announced when I press Submit. So, the reading order is what I would expect for a field that isn't labelled and doesn't use `aria-describedby`.